# Determining static method with a global LinkedList variable

Tags: java, linked-list, static-methods, static-variables

I'm having a really hard time deciding when to make my methods static or not. I was told to make a global LinkedList variable:

`public static LinkedList list = new LinkedList();`

Now, I wrote a method called `read()` to read in words from a text file. Then I wrote another method `preprocessWord(word)` to check if these words begin with a constant to change them to lower-case. If they have these conditions,  then I add them to the LinkedList list:

```
  public void read(){
  ....
  while((nextLine = inFile.readLine())!= null){

    tokens = nextLine.trim().split("\\s+");
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
        word = tokens[i];
        word = preprocessWord(word);
          list.append(word);}
    }
  }
  ...
  }//read
```

However, when I try to call `read()` from the main method;

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  read();
  System.out.println(list);

 }//main
```

The error is I cannot make a static reference to a non-static method `read()`, so I tried to change my methods `read()` and `preprocessedWord()` to static methods, but then `words` aren't updated in `preprocessedWord()` like they are suppose to. I really don't get where to use static and to where not, could someone please explain where I'm going wrong in my thinking?

Comment: Cuz your `read` method is not static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in laymen's terms, when you define a method non-static, it can only be invoked on an instance of this class. In your case however you would need to run something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new YourClassName().read();
  System.out.println(list);

 }
```

Doing so however, would mean that in your read method, you would have to access the static list as

```
YourClassName.list.append(word)
```

The other approach would be to make read static as well, so in this case your method signature should be

```
public static void read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuz your `read` method is not static. Dont use satic field unless you need to eg. for sharing reference between all objects of the same class. Make your list non-static or even local and pass as argument to subsequent methods calls